# How can I view the control sequences that my terminal is outputting in text form?

Tags: bash, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, escape-characters

I have a terminal graphical error I need to troubleshoot, and I'm not sure what the right tools for doing this are.

I'm imagining my workflow will look something like:

- turn on terminal recording program
- open program with graphical bug
- close bugged program
- halt terminal recording program
- use recorded log and bugged program's documentation to configure program correctly

The trouble is, I don't know of any programs that record *everything* another program outputs.

My first thought was to just redirect stdout to a file, but my understanding is that ascii escape codes are ignored by `>`.

In case this is only possible with a special terminal emulator, I'm using WSL. A solution in the terminal would be preferable though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> my understanding is that ascii escape codes are ignored by `>`

Not at all. It's the program who *may* detect it's writing to a non-tty and restrain itself from using escape codes.

Use [`script(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html). More solutions here: [**How to trick a command into thinking its output is going to a terminal?**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/249723/108618) I cannot tell if all of them can work in WSL though.

Note if you manage to capture the output with codes to a file, simply `cat`ing the file will make your terminal *interpret* the codes. Use `cat -A`, `less` or similar program to see representations of codes.